# Web API translating input into random int

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-web-api, json.net

not sure whether the subject is the best description for this problem but I am getting an unusual problem where I have a single Web API operation and a single field on a request and for some odd reason the value gets manipulated. Depending on the input this gets converted / translated by Web API or even by something else such as JSON.NET?

Should mention that this a brand new project with no additional references apart from what gets added by default when creating a new Web API project in Visual Studio.

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public void Post(Foo request)
    {
    }
}
public class Foo
{
    public string Blah { get; set; }
}
```

Using a rest client I hit the operation using the following request:

```
{
  "Blah": 43443333222211111117
}
```

When debugging the value of Blah gets converted to `"6549845074792007885"`. I don't understand how and why its doing this? Any other value it respects. For example:

```
{
  "Blah": 53443333222211111117
}
```

This is absolutely fine but is a bigger number.

Thanks, DS.

Comment: Can you actually have a api method which return void? I have seen they generally returns IHttpResult or HttpResponseMessage? Otherwise how would the consumer know if the request was indeed successful or not?

Comment: By default no content gets returned back. I have the http post attribute on the method too.

Comment: Did u try setting correct content type in the request header?

Comment: Yeah both headers set as json. Content type and the other one I can't remember top of my head.

Comment: Try appending frombody infront of Foo in method signature and set content type as urlencoded while posting a request and see if that makes a diff

Comment: While I'm not sure why Json.Net is converting that particular value into the string that it does without stepping through their code, if you correctly wrap your string value in double quotes then it works as expected.

Comment: Is this Json.NET doing this then? @qamar I added the FromBody attribute still same issue.

Comment: Hello DS, sorry I was way for a while. Okay I have down my research and submitted a post request using a tool called postman. And the value does not get changed. Please note that I am setting content type as x-www-form-urlencoded. See syntax here Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: This is how my raw request looks likePOST http://localhost:57912//api/Values HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:57912
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 25
CSP: active
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36
Postman-Token: 86509883-7f3d-842b-af7b-2d36617b914a
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,bn;q=0.6,ms;q=0.4,th;q=0.2

blah=43443333222211111117

Comment: This is a bug in JSON.NET. It has to do with the library attempting to turn the number into a `long` and overflowing in this case

Comment: This bug has been fixed now and will be included in the next release. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

[This bug has been fixed and is scheduled to be included in the next release](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/600#issuecomment-136124937).

**Original Answer**

This is a bug in JSON.NET as hinted at, but it's not as simple as it first seems.

Versions prior to 5.0.4 work for both of these test cases. Anything after seems to fail but only for the first test case which is odd. I've gone through some of the JSON.NET code to try and see where this confusion occurs but at present cannot work out the why this is the case, I need to do more digging.

```
2147483647                      Int Max
4444333322221111                Valid Credit Card Number Format
9223372036854775807             Int 64 Max
43443333222211111117            Dodgy Number greater than Int 64 hence overflow
53443333222211111117            Larger than above and Int 64, but works oddly.
1.7976931348623157E+308.        Decimal max
```

Why 53443333222211111117 works is very odd. JSON.NET seems to have a 1025 character buffer set aside that contains a load of jibberish for my test cases, eventually the number is read incorrectly. I'll check this out further and [raise an issue with JSON.NET](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/600).

If you use a decimal for the property this will work in all cases where the leading number is not zero, but this isn't a solution. For the short term, use version 5.0.3.

Take this example program to demonstrate the problem.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sending in: \n43443333222211111117");
            var largeBrokenNumber = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>("{\"Blah\": 43443333222211111117 }");
            Console.WriteLine(largeBrokenNumber.Blah);

            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Sending in: \n53443333222211111117");
            var largeOddWorkingNumber = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>("{\"Blah\": 53443333222211111117 }");
            Console.WriteLine(largeOddWorkingNumber.Blah);
        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public string Blah { get; set; }
    }
```